# How to use wp query in my custom page without including header and footer in wordpress

Tags: wp-query, customization

I am loading a php page using ajax. But I am not able to use the wp-query function on the custom page. Can anyone please suggest to me how I can use the wp query function on a custom page without loading header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to use require() method in PHP. It doesn't require to load header/footer in renderdata.php in order to use WP_Query() query class.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_aj_page', 'my_aj_page' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_aj_page', 'my_aj_page' );

function my_aj_page() {
    require('ajaxpage/renderdata.php');
    die();
}
```